# Set style using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to set body's background without jQuery.

Jquery code:

```js
$('body').css('background','red');
```

Why the following code won't work in pure JavaScript?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body').style['background']  = 'red';
```

Comment: Because the `.style` property applies to individual DOM elements, and `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a *list*.

Comment: I believe there should be an error throwned, check it

Comment: `getElements...` note the `s` at the end of `Elements`. Use `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style['background']`

Comment: [*getElementsByTagName*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an [*HTMLCollection*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which doesn't have a *style* property.

Comment: you should take a look at it, it is basic https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Comment: [0].style.cssText='border: 2px solid #f96666;';

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'RED';
```

```html
<div>sample</div>
```

Comment: Why did you create an `obj` variable?

Answer (score 8):

> There are many ways you can set the background color.
> But **getElementsByTagName** does not return a single object. It's a collection of objects

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; // JavaScript

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green"; // Another one
```

[See the demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FEjfjG7SM10ouhvjt4AR?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, that is a lot simpler. But it doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work. (And...green?)

Comment: getElementsByTagName return a object which hold more then one value, you can access it by it's index.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` does not return a single element, but instead a collection.

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor  = 'red';
```