# What is the correct syntax for my javascript snippet to set font size and style?

Tags: javascript, font-size

In the SBM application, I have a form action whose javascript snippet works.  It replaces commas with new lines:

```
var commaDelimValue = GetFieldValue("DEPARTMENTS_FUNCTIONS");
var convertedToList = commaDelimValue.replace(/,/g, '\n');
SetFieldValue("DEPTS_FUNCTIONS_TEXT", convertedToList, "true");
```

I want to use a similar snippet to set font size and style, but the font size and style commands are failing:

```
var projDescrValue = GetFieldValue("PROJECT_DESCRIPTION");
var fontFamilyValue = projDescrValue.style.fontFamily("Helvetica");
var fontSizeValue = fontFamilyValue.style.fontSize("9pt");

SetFieldValue("PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_COPY", fontSizeValue, "true");
```

Comment: [Duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942002/set-style-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to set the font style is:

```
object.style.fontFamily = "helvetica";
object.style.fontSize = "9pt";
```

Or

```
object.style.font = "italic bold 9pt helvetica";
```

[More information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_font.asp)

Comment: Thank you Tamas; that looks promising.  However, so far, I haven't figured out how to incorporate it into my javascript.  Specifically, I have to set either the original field or a new field that I set with the content of the first field, with Helvetica 9-point, as shown in my original question.